# What is the purpose of 'QSet<QString>presenceSubsciptions(QString JID)' method in QXmpp?

Tags: xmpp, qxmpp

I'm using QXmpp 0.7.6 library in order to implement server app. The library is itself a perfect paradigm. There is a `QXmppServer` that servers every `QXmppIncomingClient` and stores them in private QSet when client succeeds authentification on top of that there is a QXmppServerExtentsion, if you want to extend QXmppServer.

But I'm puzzled at the moment with the purpose of `QSet<QString> presenceSubsciptions(QString JID)` virtual method in `QXmppServerExtension` class?

Actually, there is no any presence handling option on QXmppServer side, so I've inherited my own PresenceExtention class from QXmppServerExtension but I dunno for what there is a `presenceSubscribtion` method. By the way, there is a one problem also, when client connected to server, it stores online clients in QSet.

But at the moment I'm not able to access presence statuses of clients to send it to clients from connected client's roster. Can guide me? Perhaps, the aforementioned method is left abstact for that goal?

Comment: do you have any code already written?

Comment: For presence subscribtion on server yes, I do